# member function bad() of std::ftsream for checking

Tags: c++

I know that i can check sucessful file opening with operator! and member function fail() of std::fstream class.

But can i use for this purpose also member function bad()? Is it standard-conforming or not?

Answer (score 2):

`ios::operator!` and `ios::bad` are not interchangeable. `operator!` checks for any error (the same as `ios::fail`), while `ios::bad` checks only for non-recoverable errors.

See their respective documentation [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/bad) and [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!).

What you need to check really depends on your use case and you need to understand the implications.

Comment: I want to check only successful file opening

Answer (score 1):

The function `bad()` yields `true` for "irrecoverable errors" - whatever that means. Basically, `bad()` is set whenever something fails for a different reason than a format error of some form. Interestingly, the `open()` function of the various file stream classes (`std::ofstream`, `std::ifstream`, and `std::fstream`) all set `std::ios_base::failbit` when the file buffer's `open()` fails! That is, you can't use `stream.bad()` to test if an `open()` failed. You can use `stream.fail()`. Personally, I wouldn't bother and use the conversion to `bool`:

```
std::ofstream out("file");
if (out) {
    process();
}
else {
    report_error();
}
```

Comment: So i can use only operator!, fail() and good() for this purpose, right?

Comment: You can use the implicit conversion to `bool`, `operator!()`, and `fail()` to determine if `open()` failed. If the file happens to be empty, `eof()` may be set immediately following a successful `open()` of the file, I think (I'm not sure, though, but it would be a bit of task to track it down). `good()` is `false` if any of the error bits is set, including `std::ios_base::eofbit`. The other three methods are sufficient anyway and I see even fewer reasonable uses of `good()` than for `eof()`.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, `ios::bad()` returns a `boolean`, and `!` will simply negate the `boolean` (that is, `true`->`false` and vice versa).

Whether or not that is what you *intend* to do is a different question. `bad()` checks for loss of integrity of a stream rather than the failure to open.

Comment: I want to check only successful file opening

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov then to directly answer your question, no. You cannot use `::bad()` for this purpose. It is not standard-conforming.